# jQuery template expression constraints

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I have:

```
<script id="foo" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <p>${100 * parseInt(x)}</p>
</script>
```

When I do:

```
$('#foo').tmpl({'x':5}) // or '5'
```

I get a TypeError (undefined method).

But if I remove the parseInt or if I move the 100 to come after the parseInt, everything works!

I've been searching and everything I find says that `${}` should be able to handle arbitrary expressions, but there seems to be some syntax magic/intolerance going on here.

Any explanations?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this:

```
 <p>100 * parseInt(${x})</p>
```

Comment: No, I don't want to render "100 * parseInt(5)"; I want to render "500."

Comment: then why don't you do it like this, $('#foo').tmpl({'x': parseInt(yourVariable)* 500})

Comment: I'm asking this question to understand why the template expression doesn't work, not to find workarounds. I already gave some example workarounds in my question.